# how to detect recreate after crash vs. recreate after normal activity destruction

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Is it possible to differentiate between the following:

A. Activity is being re-created after having been destroyed by the OS.  For instance, if the device has "Don't keep activities" enabled and the user sends my app to the background then brings it to the foreground again.

B. Activity is being re-created after an app crash.

Comment: I don't know if onStop()/onDestroy() is called on crash. If not it's simply to update a shared preference value.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to know? If you want to know when one of your users has had the app crash on him, integrate ACRA into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way as such but I don't believe that the onStop or OnDestroy is called when the activity crashes but not 100% sure.

If it doesn't, then in the onStop or onDestroy set a shared preference i.e. `shutdownCorrectly` which is set to true.

Then when the activity opens, check that the shared preference `shutdownCorrectly` run your normal code and set the shared preference to false. If the shared preference is false when you check, then it means the app crashed so you can run other code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I ended up doing, but this is an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a interface called [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) available which allows you to detect crash due to unheandled exceptions.

example : see [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/threads/uncaughtexceptionhandler/thread-uncaughtexceptionhandler-example/)